# Lista como valor de diccionario pasa a ser None al agregar elemento mediante append

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Estoy tratando de agregar un nuevo disco al diccionario pero a la hora de imprimirlo me regresa el area de los discos como None.

```
albumes = {'Disco': {'Artistas': ['Bees Gees', 'Donna Summer'],'Discos': ['Spirits Have Flown','The Wanderer'],'Anos': [1979,1980]},
               'Rock': {'Artistas': ['Electris Light Orchesta', 'Pink Floyd'],'Discos': ['Out of the blue', 'The dark side of the moon'] ,'Anos': [1977,1973]}}



donde = input('Ingrese el nombre del genero donde desea agregar un disco: ')
nombre = input('Ingrese el nombre del disco: ')
j = albumes[donde]['Discos']
albumes[donde]['Discos'] = j.append(nombre)
```

Estoy tratando de agregar el nombre a la lista que ya tenia pero me regresa none.

Comment: {'Disco': {'Artistas': ['Bees Gees', 'Donna Summer'], 'Discos': None, 'Anos': [1979, 1980]}, 'Rock': {'Artistas': ['Electris Light Orchesta', 'Pink Floyd'], 'Discos': ['Out of the blue', 'The dark side of the moon'], 'Anos': [1977, 1973]}} Esto es lo que me imprime, no se porque regresa 'None' y me elimina los discos que ya tenia.

Comment: No entiendo, dices que te imprime los valores y luego dices que te devuelve none?

Comment: @Bicho, con ese código, haces un `print(albumes)` e imprime los valores pero en lugar de agregar el disco, agrega "None"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analicemos lo que estás haciendo:

- **`j = albumes[donde]['Discos']`**: Esto busca en el diccionario `albumes` la clave `donde`, lo cual (si la encuentra) obtiene como valor un diccionario de la forma `{'Artistas': [...],'Discos': [...],'Anos': [...]}`. A continuación obtiene de dicho diccionario el valor asociado a la clave `"Discos"`, que es una lista. En este punto `j` queda asociada a una referencia a dicha lista.
- **`albumes[donde]['Discos'] = j.append(nombre)`**: primero ejecuta la parte derecha de la expresión de asignación, `j.append(nombre)`. Esto hace que se agregue nombre a la lista asociada a `j`, que es lo que en principio quieres, pero **`list.append` es un método que actúa in-place y retorna `None`**. Dicho retorno es asignado como valor a la clave `albumes[donde]['Discos']`, por lo que realmente estás haciendo:

  ```
  albumes[donde]['Discos'] = None
  ```

el elemento se añade a la lista, pero como luego se reasigna None a la clave del diccionario que antes tenia asociada la lista, esta desaparece y el GC la mandará a paseo para siempre... y el diccionario queda:

```
    {'Artistas': [...],'Discos': None,'Anos': [...]}
```

El problema es que te sobra código, simplemente debes hacer:

```
donde = input('Ingrese el nombre del genero donde desea agregar un disco: ')
nombre = input('Ingrese el nombre del disco: ')
albumes[donde]['Discos'].append(nombre)
```

o en todo caso:

```
donde = input('Ingrese el nombre del genero donde desea agregar un disco: ')
nombre = input('Ingrese el nombre del disco: ')
j = albumes[donde]['Discos']
j.append(nombre)
```

Comment: Tienes razón, prácticamente hice lo mismo dos veces. Muchas gracias!